# Why train loss stays stable and eval loss decreases when fine-tuning albert model?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a multi-classifier(26 classes) from fine-tuning the albert model. After some steps, some strange phenomenon appears. The train loss stays stable, but the eval loss remains to decrease and eval accuracy also increases. What's more, the eval loss is lower than train loss.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have more than 5M train instances and 250K eval instancse.Max seq length is 128, train batch size is 32 and eval batch size is 32, learning rate is 2e-5 and training with 4 GPUs.

How to explain?